# bash shell script for loop

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash shell script that loops through a server list file to verify a user exists on that server.  My question is, I want the script to echo out which servers the user exists on before executing command:  sleep; clear; main_sec <(this is a function) problem is as soon as that condition is met, it just echo's the first server met then executes code.  How do i echo it all out then execute the code?

```
echo -e "${YELLOW}Checking if user account exists on any of the servers above${NONE}"

readarray -t lines < servers.txt

for server in "${lines[@]}"; do
    ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $server "egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd" &>/dev/null

    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        continue
    fi

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "${RED}User account $username already exists on $server, Must choose a unique username before proceeding.  Returning to menu...${NONE}"
sleep 5; clear; main_sec 
fi
done
```

Comment: Please insert your code lines by 4 spaces, so that they get formatted as code.

Comment: The code you pasted does not run, did you mix up the last lines?

Comment: @mbarron9393 : Your `sleep` will never be executed, because you are executing a `continue` before.

Comment: I removed the continue, but it executes the code over  and over, I want it to just execute once after displaying servers that the user exists on

Comment: I want it to show:
User account  already exists on server a, Must choose a unique username before proceeding.  Returning to menu...

User account  already exists on server b, Must choose a unique username before proceeding.  Returning to menu...

User account  already exists on server c, Must choose a unique username before proceeding.  Returning to menu...

Then execute the sleep; clear; main_sec

Comment: What is 'main_sec' ? why do you clear the screen between hosts ?

Comment: the main_sec function just takes the user back to the main menu to re-input username, basically it will say "user exists on (server)"  go back and use a diff user name

Comment: @Camusensei I removed the typo, it now runs, thanks for the comment

Comment: Use a `while` loop to iterate over the lines of a file, not a `for` loop. See [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Also use http://shellcheck.net for to check for other errors and suggestions.

Comment: @chepner, if they had used a while loop, only the first line would have been read because `ssh` would have slurped the rest of the file. Explaining how and why to either use another file descriptor than `1` or closing stdin on `ssh` (with `-N` or with `</dev/null`) sounded too complicated for this answer, but in the essence, you are completely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to save a match and use it later. You can use a variable for that:

```
return_menu=
for ...; do
  if ssh ...; then
    ...
  else
    echo >&2 "User account $username already exists on $server, Must choose a unique username before proceeding. Returning to menu..."
    return_menu=return_menu
  fi
fi
done
if [[ $return_menu != '' ]]; then
  sleep 5
  clear
  main_sec
fi
```

Here is a corrected version of your code with all my advice from below:

```
#username=...
return_menu=
echo "${YELLOW}Checking if user account exists on any of the servers above$NONE"
readarray -t lines < servers.txt
for server in "${lines[@]}"; do
  if printf 'getent passwd %q >/dev/null' "$username" |
      ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$server" bash -s; then
    continue
  else
    printf >&2 '%s\n' \
      "${RED}User account $username already exists on $server." \
      "You must choose a unique username before proceeding." \
      "${NONE}Returning to menu..."
    return_menu=return_menu
fi
done
if [[ $return_menu != '' ]]; then
  sleep 5
  clear
  main_sec
  exit 0
fi
```

Some code mistakes you can avoid:

## Don't assume `$?` won't change!

Your second execution of `$?` will be `0` as it's `if`'s return code (unless you change your code)
Instead of the syntax `command; if [ $? ]`, use:

```
if ssh ...; then
  ...
else
  ...
fi
```

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf44

## Avoid `[`

`[` or `test` is the POSIX test command. It can do simple tests on files and strings. In bash, you should use the more powerful `[[` instead and ban `[` for sake of consistency. `[[` can do pattern matching, is faster and safer to use.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

## Termination

`main_sec` will launch something else, and you don't want lines further down the script continue executing once you finish so you should add an exit afterwards to be sure you really terminate when `main_sec` finishes

## `egrep` is deprecated

Use `grep -E` if needed (not needed here)

## Don't do `grep ... > /dev/null`

If you only want the return code, use `grep -q`. This avoid scanning all the input when you only want to know if a match is there. It helps for larger inputs.

## Consider using `getent` instead of /etc/passwd

Instead of scanning /etc/passwd, you should use `getent` which is designed for it
It also covers domain accounts, if it helps.

## Capital variable names

By convention, we capitalize environment variables (`PAGER`, `EDITOR`, ..) and internal shell variables (`SHELL`, `BASH_VERSION`, ..). All other variable names should be lower case. Remember that variable names are case-sensitive; this convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

## Don't use `echo` with options flags

`echo` outputs a string. `echo` has many portability problems, and should never be used with option flags. Consider `printf` instead: `printf 'name: %s\n' "$name"`.

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/echo

http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq.html#Q0b

[http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf](http://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/echo+printf)

In this case, you are using `echo -e '$RED ... $NONE'`.

I'm guessing it's because `RED='\e[31m' NONE='\e(B\e[0m'`

If you used these values instead, you could use the colors without `echo`'s `-e`:

`RED=$'\e[31m' NONE=$'\e(B\e[0m'`

## Don't assume variables will not contain special characters

Here, `username` may be set by someone who has ill intent to values such as `; rm -rf /`.
Once launched on you ssh servers, this could be disastrous. Even if you have set the username in the code yourself, you don't know if the code won't be changed in the future to some form of user-defined value, so you should protect your code against this while you still can by escaping special characters before passing them to `ssh`. There are many ways to do that, and one is:

```
printf 'getent passwd %q >/dev/null' "$username" | ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$server" bash -s
```

Comment: Thanks for the notes!  I will test this out and see how it goes.
The only reason I use the passwd file is that we have multiple OS types, i.e AIX, HP-UX and Suse.  
Thanks again for all the other tips.  I will take note

Comment: Thanks That worked perfect, thanks for the help, how do i assign points?  I'm new to this site

Comment: Accepting the answer just like you did. When you'll have more (15+) reputation, you will also be able to upvote answers. Enjoy your stay on StackOverflow!